# Joining three tables, distinct users, latest date only (auditing)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, subquery

I am currently trying to this query to yield the correct information. What I have produces results, but they aren't correct. There are three tables:

User_Details: Includes a giant list of users, along with the server they have access to. So below, you'll see ServerA is listed twice, because it has two users: user001 and user002. Not saying this is the best method, but this is what I've been handed.

```
SERVER      USER        CONNECTION
ServerA     user001     success
ServerA     user002     success
ServerB     user001     success
ServerA     user007     success
ServerB     user002     success
ServerB     user003     success
ServerC     user001     success
ServerC     user002     success
ServerC     user007     success
```

Server_Details: Includes a bunch of server data, most that I won't include here. The primary focus here is that it's a unique/distinct list of servers, along with their type. The key here that I am to include only 'Developer' servers. So below, with a properly written query it would only pick up ServerC and ServerD since they're 'Developer'.

```
SERVER      SQL SERVER EDITION  
ServerA     Standard            
ServerB     Standard        
ServerC     Developer       
ServerD     Developer
```

Audit_Details. This third table has a lot of data. It'll list a user and the server they logged into. Technically, it's called INSTANCE_NAME here and is cut off (think "ServA" instead of "ServerA"). Anyways, it lists the user, server, and the time logged on.

```
USER_ID     LAST_LOGON_TIME         INSTANCE_NAME
user001     2016-04-18 07:40:04     ServerA 
user002     2016-04-18 07:40:04     ServerA 
user002     2016-05-03 09:31:01     ServerB 
user002     2016-05-06 14:36:01     ServerC 
user003     2016-05-13 09:05:43     ServerB 
user007     2016-05-13 09:05:43     ServerA 
user007     2016-05-13 09:05:43     ServerC
```

Hopefully that gives enough of an idea of the schema I am working with. I am trying to write a query that distinctly lists all users who have access to a 'Developer' server, along where they logged into last (INSTANCE_NAME field in Audit_Details table) and when (LAST_LOGON_TIME in Audit_Details table).

Could I get any assistance? The below query is what I have so far, but it's not doing what I want.

```
select distinct u.[USER], s.[COMPUTER NAME], max([LAST_LOGON_TIME]) as [LAST LOGON TIME]
from [User_Details] u
  inner join [Server_Details] s
    on s.[Computer Name] = u.[SERVER]
  inner join [Audit_Details] a
    on a.[USER_ID] = u.[USER]
where s.[SQL Server Edition] LIKE 'dev%'
group by u.[USER], s.[COMPUTER NAME]        -- Need group by or it breaks. 
-- Error: 
-- "[USER] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
order by u.[USER] asc
```

Ideally a query looks like:

```
USER_ID     LAST_LOGON_TIME         LAST_SERVER_LOGGED_ON
user001     2016-04-18 07:40:04     ServerA 
user002     2016-04-18 07:40:04     ServerA 
user003     2016-05-03 03:31:01     ServerB 
user004     2016-05-06 14:36:01     ServerD 
user005     2016-05-13 12:05:43     ServerC 
user006     2016-05-26 09:09:43     ServerC 
user007     2016-05-29 11:05:43     ServerZ
```

This would make it easier to compile a list of active users, maybe people who have been logging in the last 2 weeks, and then talk to users who haven't been using their access in months.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way

```
select * from 
(
select distinct u.[USER], s.[COMPUTER NAME], [LAST_LOGON_TIME] as [LAST LOGON TIME]
,Row_number () over ( partition by u.[USER], s.[COMPUTER NAME] order by [LAST_LOGON_TIME] desc) rowid
from [User_Details] u
  inner join [Server_Details] s
    on s.[Computer Name] = u.[SERVER]
  inner join [Audit_Details] a
    on a.[USER_ID] = u.[USER]
    and a.instance_name = u.[SERVER]
where s.[SQL Server Edition] LIKE 'dev%'     
) as x
where rowid = 1


order by [USER] asc
```